# Scrollbar Appearing in React App When There is AppBar in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, styled-components

I have a very simple problem in my React app. How can i remove the scrollbar in my page?
I think this is because of the height that i put which is `100vh`. However, if i remove the `AppBar`, the scrollbar disappears. How would i fix this problem?

Pls check my codesandbox here [Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4gsib?file=/demo.js)

```
<div>
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Toolbar>
      <Typography variant="h6">News</Typography>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
  <Grid container component="main" className={classes.root}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={7} className={classes.image} />
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Box mt={5}>
            <Copyright />
          </Box>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `height: 100vh` for your `main` section. And the `AppBar` section is out of the `main` section. If you want to remove scrollbar, you need to remove the height of the `AppBar`, which is `64px`, when you set `height` for the `main` section:

```
height: calc(100vh - 64px);
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to do this.
First is to simply add the `position="fixed"` prop in material-ui `Appbar`. It'll make the header fixed and the rest other elements will adjust accordingly. But to keep the UI the same add padding equals the `Appbar` height (around 64px).

The second method is to just add the `paddingTop` to `Grid` container equals to the `Appbar` height keeping the `position="static"` prop same. or also another way is to minus the appbar height from total height i.e; `"calc(100vh - 64px)"`

The important point is here to decrease the appbar height from the Grid container for static appBar

Answer (score 0):

AppBar size (height) may not always be 64px, maybe in your case its fine.

In my case

```
<AppBar position="sticky">
```

fixed the issue.

If this doesn't work in your case, there might be some other styling affecting the result.

For context, I also have the below styles

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, #root {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Where **#root** is the main (root) div with id **root** where React renders all the components

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
```